# Flexbox next to a float -- why/how does it take up remaining space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

It appears when a flexbox is placed next to a `float: left`, it takes up the remaining space, and does not wrap around the float.

How and why is this happening? Can any other `display` accomplish this, or is it unique to flexbox?

```css
.float {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1)
}

.regular-div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,255,255,.1);
}

.table {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<b>Example one: Float with a div next to it</b>
<div>
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<b>Example two: Float with a flexbox next to it</b>
<div>
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
      I'm a flexbox. I do not wrap the div, and I occupy the remaining space to the right.<br>
      Why does this happen?
      Can any other "display" do this?
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<b>Example three: Float with a table next to it</b>
<div>
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="table">
      I am a table.<br>
      I position myself like a flexbox<br>
      But I shrink to fit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/):

> A flex container establishes a **new flex formatting context** for its contents. This is the same as establishing **a block formatting context**, except that flex layout is used instead of block layout. For example, **floats do not intrude into the flex container**, and the flex container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents. Flex containers form a containing block for their contents exactly like block containers do. [CSS21] The overflow property applies to flex containers.

A regular div will do the same if you apply overflow to it (it will create a block formatting context)

```css
.float {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1)
}

.regular-div {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,255,255,.1);
}

.table {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<b>Example one: Float with a div next to it</b>
<div>
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<b>Example two: Float with a flexbox next to it</b>
<div>
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
      I'm a flexbox. I do not wrap the div, and I occupy the remaining space to the right.<br>
      Why does this happen?
      Can any other "display" do this?
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>
<b>Example three: Float with a table next to it</b>
<div>
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="table">
      I am a table.<br>
      I position myself like a flexbox<br>
      But I shrink to fit.
  </div>
</div>
```

So this is not really related to the display property but to the creation  of a block formatting context. If it's the case, then float will behave differently.

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, **or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context** (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, **but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position)</sup>

---

For the width, it's a different story. A table element will not fill all the remaining space because its width is defined by the *shrink-to-fit* algorithm (like `inline-block` and `float`!). Such element will not interact with the float element and will have their width fit their content.

Some other examples:

```css
.float {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1)
}

.regular-div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
}
.main {
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div" style="display:inline-block;">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div" style="float:left;">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div" style="display:grid;">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div" style="display:inline-flex;">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
  <div class="float">
    I am floating left.
  </div>

  <div class="regular-div" style="columns:1">
      I'm a regular div after the float.
      <br>My content should wrap around the float.
      <br>Look at it go!
      <br>Wow!
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find here a full list of properties that create a block formatting context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

To conclude: if you want your element to fill the remaining space after a float element, you need to make sure it creates a BFC and it's not a *shrink-to-fit* element and it's an in-flow element (you can create a BFC using `position:absolute`)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.  I assume that a `table` also establishes a new block formatting context?

Comment: @JS_Riddler yes it does

Comment: @JS_Riddler added more details

Answer (score 0):

The wrapping effect around [floated elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats) works only with [inline boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous). These are, basically, runs of text.

Block level containers are not inline boxes and, therefore, do not wrap around floated elements.